# Getting state old value on React custom hook callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React custom hooks has been written. On Callback the react state has been updated but getting the state old value in the custom hook callback.

In the example, we can see that on each button click the updated state value will be shown inside the component, but we will get the old previous value inside the callback.

For testing purpose, I have added a settimeout. But with or without setTimeout, I am getting the old state value inside the custom hook callback.

**Hook:**

```
const useStateWithCallbackLazy = (initialValue) => {
  const callbackRef = React.useRef(null);

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialValue);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (callbackRef.current) {
      // call back method has been called with the value
       callbackRef.current(value);
        callbackRef.current = null;
    }
  }, [value]);

  const setValueWithCallback = React.useCallback((newValue, callback) => {
    callbackRef.current = callback;
    debugger;
    setValue(newValue);
  }, []);

  return [value, setValueWithCallback];
};
```

**Inside component:**

```
 const [count, setCount] = useStateWithCallbackLazy(0);

  const checkTheCountValue = () => {
    console.log('current count value - ' + count);
  };
  
  const handleClick = () => {
    setCount(count + 1, (currentCount) => {
     // Callback method
      checkTheCountValue();
    });
  };
```

**Demo code**: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-gagarin-mucxzh

Referred code from the following plugin.
https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/use-state-with-callback

Comment: And why don't you use the `currentCount` value?

Comment: That is actually right. But I need to pass this value to functions. If I have multiple nested functions, I need to pass all the way. I need to get rid of this and should access the latest value. How can I do that?

Comment: Actually I have done plain settimeout inside handclick. But still goes out of the updated component state. why do callback and settimeout goes out of the current state?

Comment: The problem with this is that `React`'s `setState` is asynchronous. So when you call `setCount` (that is `setValue` internally) it won't update the `count` immediately. You have to wait for the update to happen in order to get the updated value. On possible solutions would be to use an `useEffect` hook and set `count` in the dependency array. So once the `count` value is updated, `useEffect` callback will be triggered and you can use the updated value there.

Comment: Yes, I understood. That's why I have added setTimeout inside the customhook. 
If you run the demo, you could see that after click the button, the values will be rendered in the screen and then the console log will be fired. 
Inside the consol log, old values are retained.
Check - https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-gagarin-mucxzh

Answer (score 1):

According to your codebase, the `checkTheCountValue` function always logs the previous `count`.
At the point of calling the `handleClick` function, the `checkTheCountValue` function logs the value of `count` before setting a new value.

I have modified your code like this.

```
const checkTheCountValue = (value) => {
  console.log('current count value - ' + value);
};

const handleClick = () => {
  setCount(count + 1, checkTheCountValue);
};
```

Comment: This also provides the same result that I have mentioned. Can you please modify and check? 
https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-gagarin-mucxzh

Comment: @JeevaJ, focus on the `checkTheCountValue` function.

Comment: @JeevaJ please check this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-hooks-tri5g7)

Comment: You are passing the callback value that is passed from the custom hooks.
This can be achieved from my sample too. 
But the problem is I have multiple nested functions. Whether I need or not, I need to pass this value to multiple nested functions. 
That's why, I need to access the current state value from the component. 
Instead I need

Comment: Check the sample:- https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-shockley-2mn87f?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @JeevaJ, I think your `handleClick` function is essentially the same as mine.

Comment: Yes, but what I wanted to convey is, you are sending the value that is sent from the callback. I don't want that. I want to access state value. Since you are confused, I have edited as my need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249625/discussion-between-bikas-lin-and-jeeva-j).

Comment: At the point of calling `setState` function using `custom hook`, the `callback` function has been already passed to the `custom hook` with the previous `state` value.
So there is no way to access the new `state` value in callback without passing from `custom hook`, I think.
But if you use `useEffect` for tracking the updates of `state`, there is no problem.
If you use `callback` just for the purpose of executing it after `state` is updated, you can use just `useEffect` for that purpose.